# SOQL vs Sync Analytics API

Tags: managed-package, analytics-api

I have some simple code in a managed package to populate a selectoption list e.g.

```
List<SelectOption> camps = new List<SelectOption> ();
for (Campaign c: [Select Id, Name FROM Campaign WHERE IsActive = TRUE] ) {
    camps.add(new SelectOption (c.Id, c.Name));
}
```

That works fine with one drawback - letting installed customers add additional filters is tricky - I've built tools to let them do that in the past, but they get messy...

But I realized I am able to achieve the same via the Analytics API and a Sync Report. I can store the Report Id in a C/S and then let customers add more filters to the report using the standard report builder. I did a quick test and the performance seemed better via the Analytics API, which surprised me a bit.

My question is whether anyone else has used this approach, in particular in a managed package. If so, beyond the users changing the report, which I can see being an issue, are there any other risks involved with this vs SOQL?